# Mock a method with an object parameter with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, matcher, stubbing

In my unit test i want to mock the interaction with elasticsearch by doing the following

```
when(cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(geoPoint, SOURCE, 2)).thenReturn(cityDefinitionsArrival);
when(cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(geoPoint2, SOURCE, 2)).thenReturn(cityDefinitionsDeparture);
SearchResult results = benerailService.doSearch(interpretation, 2, false);
```

the doSearch method contains

```
departureCityDefinitions = cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(geo, SOURCE, distance);
```

When i debug my code i see that mockito is called in my doSearch method but it does not return the cityDefinitionsArrival object. This is probably because geoPoint and geo are two different objects.

The geoPoint and geo object are both elasticsearch GeoPoints which contain the same latitude and longitude.

I managed to get this to work by doing

```
when(cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(any(geoPoint.getClass()), eq(SOURCE), eq(2))).thenReturn(cityDefinitionsArrival);
when(cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(any(geoPoint2.getClass()), eq(SOURCE), eq(2))).thenReturn(cityDefinitionsDeparture);
```

But now it ignores my latitude and longitude values and accepts any object of the GeoPoint class. This is a problem because in my doSearch method i have two usages of the findCitiesNearby, each with different latitude and longitude and I need to mock them both individually.

Is this possible with Mockito?

*The cityDefinitionsArrival and cityDefinitionsDeparture are both ArrayLists,
the SOURCE is a String value and
the geo and geoPoint object:*

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(50.850449999999995, 4.34878);
GeoPoint geoPoint2 = new GeoPoint(48.861710, 2.348923);

double lat = 50.850449999999995;
double lon = 4.34878;
GeoPoint geo = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

double lat2 = 48.861710;
double lon2 = 2.348923;
GeoPoint geo2 = new GeoPoint(lat2, lon2);
```

Comment: Just so everyone is clear, you want to mock behavior when a `GeoPoint` object has certain lat/lng coordinates, is that right?

Comment: If the `GeoPoint` class defines an `equals` method, I think you should should be able to use the `eq()` matcher. If not, implement a custom Mockito `ArgumentMatcher`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen what does it do by default then? a `==` comparison?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Correct, returning cityDefinitionsArrival or cityDefinitionsDeparture depends on the latitude and longitude that is used. if geo, then return cityDefinitionsArrival. if geo2, then return cityDefinitionsDeparture.

Comment: @weston The default `Object.equals()` invocation, which is indeed a `==` comparison.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen No I mean, if you do **not** use the `eq` matcher and the type **does** override `equals`, what does it use?

Comment: @weston Identity comparison, as per your assumption.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, But the GeoPoint object is an object from Elasticsearch, not one i created myself. Creating an extended class isn't an option either. if I would do that, elastic wouldn't accept the object anymore.

Comment: @GlennVanSchil See the second half of my comment.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen OK, I was just confused by your comment as it can't call explicitly call `Object.equals()`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, sorry i missed that part!

Comment: @GlennVanSchil I added it later :) Should be as simple as implementing a `class GeoPointMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<GeoPoint>` and its `matches()` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Use `argThat`](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html):

```
public final class IsSameLatLong extends ArgumentMatcher<GeoPoint> {

  private final GeoPoint as;

  public IsSameLatLong(GeoPoint as) {
      this.as = as;
  }

  //some sensible value, like 1000th of a second i.e. 0° 0' 0.001"
  private final static double EPSILON = 1.0/(60*60*1000); 

  private static boolean closeEnough(double a, double b) {
     return Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON;
  }

  public boolean matches(Object point) {
      GeoPoint other = (GeoPoint) point;
      if (other == null) return false;
      return closeEnough(other.getLat(), as.getLat()) &&
             closeEnough(other.getLong(), as.getLong());
  }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
when(cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(argThat(new IsSameLatLong(geoPoint)), eq(SOURCE), eq(2))).thenReturn(cityDefinitionsArrival);
when(cityDefinitionRepository.findCitiesNearby(argThat(new IsSameLatLong(geoPoint2)), eq(SOURCE), eq(2))).thenReturn(cityDefinitionsDeparture);
```

Comment: Why `ArgumentMatcher<List>` instead of `ArgumentMatcher<GeoPoint>`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen because I copied and pasted from [here](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html)! thanks!

Comment: Gotcha. Upvoted. I think the double comparison will not cause issues if both doubles are initialized using the same literal representation (e.g. `48.861710`) as this should also result in the same bit representation.

Comment: It almost works! When i use only one "when" statement it works fine but when i have them both i get a nullpointer on "return closeEnough(other.getLat(), as.getLat()) &&"

Comment: I've added a null check line